# Find $[T(a+bx)]_{B^{'}}$

Tags: linear-algebra

The transformation is given as $T(a+bx)=a+b(x+1)$, The old basis is $B=\{-1,x\}$ and the new basis is $B^{'}=\{2-x,1+x\}$. Now I'm trying to find $[T(a+bx)]_{B^{'}}$ using the coordinate vector $[x]_{B}$, i.e. $[T(a+bx)]_{B^{'}}=[T]_{B^{'}\to B}[x]_{B}$, $[T]_{B^{'}\to B}=\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
-\frac{1}{3} & 1
\end{pmatrix}$, this is correct but I can't seem to get the coordinate vector correctly, I would think that $[x]_{B}=(-a-b, b)^T$ but this isn't correct.

Comment: Your notation seems unusual.  I, personally, wouldn't write $\begin{bmatrix}T\end{bmatrix}_{B'\rightarrow B}$ because that's doing two steps at once (the transformation and the change of basis).  Also, $B'\rightarrow B$ usually means that the basis is changing from $B'$ to $B$, but you're starting with a vector with respect to the basis $B$, not $B'$ (namely $\begin{bmatrix}x\end{bmatrix}_B$).

Comment: If I understand what you’ve written correctly, the old basis seems like a red herring to me.

Comment: The problem was I was finding the transform of the coordinate vector with respect to the basis instead of just the coordinate vector with respect to the basis. As for the notation it's from Elementary Applications of Linear Algebra by Howard Anton, 11th edition.